# Can this multivariable function exist?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

(3) Is there a function of two variables whose z = 0 level curve consists exactly of the circles $x^2$ + $y^2$ = 4 and $x^2$ + $y^2$ = 10? If so, what is an example? If not, why not?

I initially set them up as two separate functions $f_1$(x,y) = $x^2$ + $y^2$ - 4 and $f_2$(x,y) = $x^2$ + $y^2$ - 10 and tried to find a way to equate them by setting them equal to 0. That didn't really get me anywhere, and I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Did you try the product, $f_1f_2$?

Comment: DRANK @Isaac Kretzmer